# VC Dimentions of Multi-Layer Perceptron

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In which conditions is the Vapnik–Chervonenkis dimension of a non-linear Multi-Layer Perceptron close to that of a linear one?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question over at CorssValidated or Computer Science SE. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25952/calculating-vc-dimension-of-a-neural-network and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/what-are-alternatives-to-vc-dimension-for-measuring-the-complexity-of-neural-net

Comment: thnx for the info .. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the weights are smaller,

Explanation: I assume your network is with sigmoidal hidden units. In sigmoidal units if the wights are smaller, it will work like a linear neuron (often called linear region of the sigmoidal neuron which is middle are of a sigmoidal neuron)